# Is the sentence "The fire sent everybody running out of the cinema" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

I have found in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English [1](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/send#google_vignette) the following :

> **Send**:affect:to make someone or something start to be in a particular state.  
> e.g. His lectures always **send** me **to sleep**.  
> **Send sb/sth into sth**  
> e.g. The tail broke apart, sending the plane into a dive.

I have found in English-Greek Dictionary of Fytrakis the following :

> **Send**:affect:to make someone or something start to be in a particular state.  
> e.g.The fire sent everybody running out of the cinema.

I cannot create a link for that because English-Greek Dictionary of Fytrakis is not an online dictionary. Is the sentence **"The fire sent everybody running out of the cinema"** correct?

Comment: Is English your mother language? Can I say 'The fire sent everybody to run out of the cinema ' or 'The fire is sending everybody to run out of the cinema now ' or 'The fire is sending everybody running out of the cinema now' or 'The fire will send everybody to run out of the cinema' or 'The fire will send everybody running out of the cinema'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this sentence is correct and idiomatic.

> The fire sent everybody running out of the cinema.

Another of your examples occurs, but is relatively less common:

> His lectures always send me to sleep.

The phrase "put to sleep" is idiomatic, so it should be

> His lectures always **put** me to sleep.

Following the comment below pointing out the occurrence of "send x to sleep" as well as "put x to sleep", I checked google ngram for the relative frequency of the two terms.
[Google Ngram viewer put * to sleep, send * to sleep](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20%2A%20to%20sleep%2C%20send%20%2A%20to%20sleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cput%20%2A%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bput%20him%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20me%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20her%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20you%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20them%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20it%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20us%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20himself%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20people%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20myself%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Csend%20%2A%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsend%20him%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20me%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20you%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20her%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20them%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20us%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20one%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20it%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20people%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20myself%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cput%20*%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bput%20him%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20me%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20her%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20you%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20them%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20it%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20us%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20himself%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20people%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20myself%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Csend%20*%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsend%20him%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20me%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20you%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20her%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20them%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20us%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20one%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20it%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20people%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsend%20myself%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0)

**Put** is much more common, but **send** occurs as well, so it is idiomatic, but more than ten times less common.

Comment: *Put* is more common, but I wouldn't say *send* is incorrect. Here's one dictionary that mentions it: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/put-send-someone-to-sleep

Comment: _Put to sleep_ suggests euthanasing an animal to me.

Comment: @KateBunting Probably because that euphemism is based on the idiom. I think the idiom still stands in its own right as correct.

Comment: @Justin  Interesting. I checked google ngram on some expressions with different pronouns. "send" is more common by a factor of more than 10; but you're right, it's not incorrect.

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish Well, of course it is, but I meant that the phrase is most often used in that context (at least in the UK), so it sounds odd to use it of a person.

Comment: Is English your mother language? Can I say 'The fire is sending everybody to run out of the cinema now ' or 'The fire is sending everybody running out of the cinema now' or 'The fire will send everybody to run out of the cinema' or 'The fire will send everybody running out of the cinema'?

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou English is my mother tongue. "The fire sent everyone running out..." is correct, "sent everyone to run" is not correct. Because of the meaning, the expression is much more likely in past tense than in present progressive or future.

Comment: 'The fire sent everybody to run out of the cinema' is wrong. Are my sentences 'The fire is sending everybody to run out of the cinema now ' or 'The fire is sending everybody running out of the cinema now' or 'The fire will send everybody to run out of the cinema' or 'The fire will send everybody running out of the cinema' also wrong?

Comment: The only ones that are wrong are the ones with "to run". The ones with "running" are grammatically correct.